# Unexpected NPM PeerDependency Error

Tags: reactjs, npm, semantic-versioning

FYI: my understanding of npm's semantic versioning comes from [the npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver) and [this article](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/mystical-magical-semver-ranges-used-npm-bower/).

I'm upgrading React from version 0.13.3 to 0.14.8 in a project with a lot of dependencies. When I run 'npm install' I would expect to get peerDependency errors for packages that specify version compatibility that React@0.14.8 doesn't satisfy.

...instead, I'm getting errors for EVERY dependency that lists React as a peerDependency, even if v0.14.8 satisfies the peerDependency semver specification:
[image: The cli error.]

Examining the error thrown by the first package: react-color-picker 2.1.9 wants a version of React greater than or equal to 0.12.0. This is specified in react-color-picker's package.json:

[image]

...but 0.14.8 is indeed greater than 0.12.0. So why is this error being thrown?

Furthermore, even if I manually modify one of these problem package's React peerDependency spec to 'want' exactly the version that I'm giving it (v0.14.8), npm still throws a peerDependency error for that package:

changing 'react-color-picker' package.json peerDependency spec to:

[image]

...results in:
[image]

Wat?

Edit 1:
This problem isn't holding the project back; manually upgrading the packages causing the errors to their most-recent versions actually eliminates the errors. But I'm wondering why npm throws those errors in the first place if there aren't any visible issues with the peerDependency specs.

...also, in case it provides more insight, here's the package.json file:
[image]

Edit 2:
Though it certainly doesn't fix anything, individual errors can be silenced by removing the react peerDependency spec from the package.json of a package that errors, like so:
[image]

...after doing this, however, packages that are erroring in spite of react peerDependency specs that look like they should work still error.

Comment: You could try the lastest versions of nodejs and npm. Its looks like a bugs. Otherwise, After updating React have you tried to reinstall all modules at once ? Could you share package.json config?

Comment: Re node and npm: 
The project is at a point that upgrading node and npm are not trivial, so I'd like to see if there's another option.

Re reinstalling all at once post-React upgrade:
Have tried that; npm still throws the same errors.

Comment: This may be a difference in version between global and local installs. Check to what versions you have installed globally vs locally and then make sure that the peer dependencies are installed in the same node_modules directory.

Comment: Also in your first screenshot it looks like react-waypoint wants to use react@0.13.x which would be a problem if you are using 0.14.8. Same for react-dnd and react-select.

Comment: @KCaradonna: 
Have checked global vs local versioning, all versions are as expected. (Ie, that doesn't appear to be the problem.)

Re react-waypoint, react-dnd, and react-select, if I remove the React peerDependency spec from their package.json's the other packages still throw the same errors. (Didn't mention this in the original question, editing it to reflect this now.)

Comment: I can see you'r using react 0.13 as dependency in you screenshot. I think you should remove it when using react 0.14 as peer dependency

Answer (score 0):

Peer dependencies are special, so I'm sorry if I start by restating the basics.

NPM asks itself "Is the dependency I see already satisfied?  If not, let me install some version at the highest level of the directory tree I can find."  When one version of 'superfoo' is required by you program, and the 'superbar' package you required needs another version of 'superfoo', npm installs a version in `./node_packages` and another in `./node_packages/superbar/node_packages`.  NPM doesn't optimize the tree to install as few copies as possible.  If you run an `npm -la | more` you will get a sense of how many copies of packages are installed everywhere.

Then you get Peer Dependencies.   These are special in that installing a new copy won't work.   The idea is that "react-color-picker" or any other peer needs to interact with that exact version already installed.   If "react-color-picker" wants 0.14.x and "react-waypoint" wants 0.13.x, there is no way to satisfy them both, so npm just gives up.  That's what happens here.

You might grep through all the React dependencies to find the odd one out.   The error messages could be better.   Start by checking 'react-waypoint' and 'react-color-picker'.   If you have a legitimate conflict, meaning two packages trying to plug into different, incompatible versions, you need to figure it out and change some JavaScript code.  It's not all just package.json bookkeeping.